# Is there a way in the Firefox plugin creation process where one can change code and check it by simply refreshing the page?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a way in the Firefox plugin creation process (just like in Google Chrome) where one can change code and check it by simply refreshing the page? Currently, I find I need to restart Firefox to check my code.

Comment: i need to restart my firefox whenever i do changes in my code..is there a method so that i don't neeed to restart it again and again and check it by simply refreshing the page?

Comment: sorry...but plz help me....i didn't mean to shout...

Comment: @preet: i added the coment also...u can see it above...if u know something related to it plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read an apply all the hints found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment -- in particular, you *must* flip all the preferences in your development profile, otherwise you'll get crazy. Also, the `-purgecaches` switch is really important, because without it, some files may persist in cache across restarts.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Developer Assistant](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-developer/) add-on there is a "Refresh all chrome" thingy, you can drag to your add-on bar. It's also the only way to see start-up errors (maybe you'll need [Console2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/) too, for seeing start-up errors). It's a bit buggy tho, it makes some other add-ons crash, breaks the menu-less layout and after the first restart when used heavily it reopens a bunch of tabs and windows.

I personally use [Restartless Restart](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restartless-restart/?src=ss). It's just a matter of Ctrl+Alt+R to restart the browser within 3-4 seconds (keeps cash, thus very fast).

Comment: thank u...i have installed it...think it is the only way better than all....thanks